# Control Flow for Buttons - Turning a Set On and Off

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a world map that allows users to select which regions they would like to see data for.

I have built a feature that, instead of clicking all six continents, users can press a button and select all.

Problem is, if a few users selected some continents prior to the select all button, the toggleClass jquery function and leave those continents inactive.

I've been trying to think of a way where I can toggle this.

```
$('#globe').on("click", function() {
    $('#globe').toggleClass('clicked')
    $('#north_america path').addClass('clicked')
    $('#south_america path').addClass('clicked')
    $('#australia path').addClass('clicked')
    $('#asia path').addClass('clicked')
    $('#africa path').addClass('clicked')
    $('#europe path').addClass('clicked')
});
```

At the moment, I have the above which allows me to turn them all on, but I can't turn them all off. Struggling to think of the control flow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep this approach you could just delete all clicked classes

```
$('.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
```

However with this one click event you still need to know when to turn everything off and when turn everything on.

But this is very easy with jQuery's function 'hasClass'

Your full code could be this:

```
$('#globe').on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
      $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
      return true;
    }
    $('#globe').addClass('clicked')
    $('#north_america path').addClass('clicked')
    $('#south_america path').addClass('clicked')
    $('#australia path').addClass('clicked')
    $('#asia path').addClass('clicked')
    $('#africa path').addClass('clicked')
    $('#europe path').addClass('clicked')
});
```